# Uploaded image in blob through android and retrieving through c#

Tags: c#, android, image, base64, blob

I have uploaded images in **blob using android and now when i am retrieving it using asp, is throws not valid Base64 string,two or more padding values**.
while encoding and decoding in android works

**Android**

```
  public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.URL_SAFE);
    return encodedImage;
   }
```

**ASP**

```
  byte[] imgByte = Convert.FromBase64String(myReader["image"].ToString());
     File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\fic.jpg", imgByte);
```

Comment: Why did you use `Base64.URL_SAFE` flag? I guess `Base64.NO_WRAP` instead in your case.

Comment: Tried this, but not working...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Done by replacing myReader["image"].ToString() with GetString()